# Showing local pdf file available in documents directory of iOS using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am facing an issue in showing pdf using html or phonegap or javascript. Its a web application which I am developing in Sencha Touch 2. My exact requirement is as follows :

- I want to show the pdf file present in documents directory using phonegap/html5/javascript (it will do in any technology I mentioned) in Web View. Currently I am using the iframe for displaying its working fine on desktop browser but when I run the same on iPhone its not showing the whole pdf (scroll is not working on iPhone).
- It will be gr8 if anybody will give me the best solution. Its urgent...:)

Thanks in advance...:)

Regards,
Shashikant.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Child Browser Plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser) for iOS

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(pathToPdf);
```

For Android, open the file in an external PDF viewer

```
navigator.app.loadUrl(pathToPdf);
```